# TDWM Throttle violation for Concurrent Sessions: For Rule Name 'BlockEndUsers', Limit of 0 concurrent requests for User

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I m facing an issue with Teradata throttle violation. I am getting this error 
Java::JavaSql::SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 16.10.00.07] [Error 3153] [SQLState HY000] TDWM Throttle violation for Concurrent Sessions: For Rule Name 'BlockEndUsers', Limit of 0 concurrent requests for User

Any suggestions would be appreciated and Thanks for spending your time.

I was trying to connect to teradata using my automation script, made the connection strings. This was working upto last week, but suddenly i m getting this error. Not sure about this. Also found out in Teradata docs

3151 TDWM Throttle violation for Concurrent Queries: %VSTR
Explanation:
This error occurs if a query request is aborted by Teradata TDWM for a Throttle rule violation. Check currently active Teradata TDWM rules.

Generated By:
Dispatcher.

For Whom:
End User.

Remedy:
Wait for system activity to subside or contact your TDWM Administrator.

I waited for some time and tried running my script still it gives me the same error.

Expected results the teradata connection should be successful.

Comment: A TDWM (or TASM) throttle rule is something imposed by DBA / System Administrator at your site. It's not something that can be "solved" in a public forum.

Comment: to add to Fred: and as the Rule is named "BlockEndUsers", it seems that you're not allowed / intended to access and you get the error by intention.